# How to get current controller name with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to active menu item in MVC with jquery.

```
  <ul id="menunav" class="nav nav-pills">
   <li>
     <a href="/reportgenerator/index">Reports</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="/account/roles">User Groups</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="/projectstatedefinition/index">Projects</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

I created this menu with `@Html.Navigation()`.

I want to get current controller in jquery for add active class to selected menu.

```
highlightActiveMenuItem = function () {
var currentAction = ???;
var currentController = ???;

};
```

Comment: Side note: since there is no direct correlation between url and controller/action names you'd be better off to pass that information view model and render in the view... Also view may be shared between multiple actions to make things even more complicated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 highlightActiveMenuItem();
});

highlightActiveMenuItem = function () {
  var url = window.location.pathname;
   $('.menu a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('active_menu_item');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
highlightActiveMenuItem = function () {
    var currentAction = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()';
    var currentController = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()';
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this code return `@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()` for currentaction.

Comment: and for the currentController?

Comment: It is return string value like action.

Comment: highlightActiveMenuItem = function () {
    var currentAction = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]';
    var currentController = '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]';
};

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function currntcontrol(){
     alert('@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()');
}
    </script>
    <button onclick="currntcontrol()"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks but this return `'@HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()'` in alert.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh27 : don't use this in js file

Comment: @ViewBag.controllername = @HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
store it viewbag